# PHP Parse SOAP XML Response

Tags: php, xml, soap, simplexml

I can't figure out how to parse this XML response though I tried working with `namespaces` and simpleXML but still no result...any Ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header />
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns3:GetDistrictByAddressResponse xmlns:ns3="http://il/co/bar/webservices/getdistrictbyaddress">
            <TimeFrameTable>
                <CustomerNumber>250</CustomerNumber>
                <Row>
                    <WindowDate>10052016</WindowDate>
                    <WeekDay>Sunday</WeekDay>
                    <FromHour>1130</FromHour>
                    <ToHour>1430</ToHour>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <WindowDate>10052016</WindowDate>
                    <WeekDay>Sunday</WeekDay>
                    <FromHour>1430</FromHour>
                    <ToHour>1730</ToHour>
                </Row>
            </TimeFrameTable>
        </ns3:GetDistrictByAddressResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Which information do you need from it ?

Comment: Only `Row` entries

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[xpath](https://php.net/manual/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) is your friend:

```
xpath('//Row');
```

---

**Full example:**

```
$soap = <<< LOL
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header />
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns3:GetDistrictByAddressResponse xmlns:ns3="http://il/co/bar/webservices/getdistrictbyaddress">
            <TimeFrameTable>
                <CustomerNumber>250</CustomerNumber>
                <Row>
                    <WindowDate>10052016</WindowDate>
                    <WeekDay>Sunday</WeekDay>
                    <FromHour>1130</FromHour>
                    <ToHour>1430</ToHour>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <WindowDate>10052016</WindowDate>
                    <WeekDay>Sunday</WeekDay>
                    <FromHour>1430</FromHour>
                    <ToHour>1730</ToHour>
                </Row>
            </TimeFrameTable>
        </ns3:GetDistrictByAddressResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
LOL;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($soap);
foreach ($xml->xpath('//Row') as $item)
{
    print_r($item);
}
```

---

**Output:**

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [WindowDate] => 10052016
    [WeekDay] => Sunday
    [FromHour] => 1130
    [ToHour] => 1430
)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [WindowDate] => 10052016
    [WeekDay] => Sunday
    [FromHour] => 1430
    [ToHour] => 1730
)
```

---

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/l5vG3a)

Comment: in my case it is not working, as i showed up here, please help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983841/php-parsing-a-soap-xml